# SQL Joins Not Working as Want

Tags: mysql, sql

I had Two Tables Like

Los Table

```
+-------------+---------+---------+-----+
| player_name | user_id | tour_id | los |
+-------------+---------+---------+-----+
| P1          |       1 |       3 |   1 |
| P2          |       1 |       3 |   3 |
| P3          |       1 |       3 |   2 |
| P4          |       1 |       3 |   2 |
| P5          |       1 |       3 |   2 |
| P6          |       1 |       3 |   1 |
| P7          |       1 |       3 |   1 |
| P8          |       1 |       3 |   0 |
+-------------+---------+---------+-----+
```

And

Win Table

```
+-------------+---------+---------+-----+
| player_name | user_id | tour_id | win |
+-------------+---------+---------+-----+
| P1          |       1 |       3 |   2 |
| P2          |       1 |       3 |   0 |
| P3          |       1 |       3 |   1 |
| P4          |       1 |       3 |   1 |
| P5          |       1 |       3 |   1 |
| P6          |       1 |       3 |   2 |
| P7          |       1 |       3 |   2 |
| P8          |       1 |       3 |   3 |
+-------------+---------+---------+-----+
```

And I want Players Name ,Los From First, Win From Second

I want to Group By Player Name But It will Giving Wrong Result

```
select player_name, los.los, win.win
from los,win
group by player_name;
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.  Hint:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Don't have two tables.

Comment: I doubt that any answer involving a join (explicit or otherwise) will be appropriate.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Whenever you join there has to be a joining condition else it will do a cartesian product.

```
select los.player_name, sum(los.los), sum(win.win)
from los,win
where los.player_name = win.player_name
group by los.player_name;
```

Comment: Thanks bro..u saved me a tons of time..problem solved..:)

Comment: I dont I am Not Allow To Vote even